# Composing groovy closures with multiple parameters

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to create a simple groovy script that will download some JSON from a website, pretty print it, and then save it to a file. I'm using this as an exercise to learn how to practice some functional concepts and I'm running into an issue I can't figure out. Basically, the last composed closure has multiple params and I can't figure out how to apply it. **I'd like the end result to be a one liner that specifies the URL and file location to save the contents**.

```
def getJson = { sourceUrl ->
    def conn = new URL(sourceUrl).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    return conn.inputStream.text
}

def prettyPrintJson = { json ->
    return groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
}

def save = { data, fileLocation ->
    new File(fileLocation).write(data)
}

def sync = getJson >> prettyPrintJson >> save
sync('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') // don't know how to specify the fileLocation
```

Answer (score 2):

If you compose functions, your innermost function determines the
arguments.  So you could provide the second argument to `save` via
`rcurry`.  E.g.:

```
def sync = getJson >> prettyPrintJson >> save.rcurry("/tmp/out.json")
sync('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

Or you would have to thread the second argument down the line until you
need it.  E.g.:

```
def getJson = { sourceUrl, out ->
    [sourceUrl.toURL().text, out]
}

def prettyPrintJson = { json, out ->
    [groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json), out]
}

def save = { data, fileLocation ->
    new File(fileLocation).write(data)
}

def sync = getJson >> prettyPrintJson >> save
sync('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', '/tmp/out.json')
```

I'd imagine, that by using a macro (since 2.5) there should be a chance to
create a threading macro (e.g. like in Clojure).

Comment: For the fun of it - here is an [attempt in a thread-first macro](https://github.com/christoph-frick/groovy-macro-musings/blob/main/ext/src/main/groovy/net/ofnir/groovymacromusings/macros/ThreadingMacroMethods.groovy)